# What is the correct context for appengine taskqueue in go112 standard runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I cannot get the appengine taskqueue to accept any context I throw at it:

```
import (
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue"
)

   /* snip */

    ctx:= context.Background()
    task := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/b/mytask", params)
    _, err = taskqueue.Add(ctx, task, "")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("adding background task with path %s: %v", task.Path, err)
    }
```

I'm calling appengine.Main() in my main.go main func as stated by the [go111 migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) (But this line is missing in [go112 migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/go-differences) so I'm not sure it's required).

I've tried:

```
context.Background()
request.Context()
appengine.NewContext(r)
appengine.BackgroundContext()
context.TODO()
```

All result in error:

> not an App Engine context

except for `appengine.BackgroundContext()` which gets:

> service bridge HTTP failed: Post
>   http://appengine.googleapis.internal:10001/rpc_http: dial tcp
>   169.254.169.253:10001: i/o timeout

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same problems when migrating a GAE standard project from go19 to go112 in order to use go modules. In addition I got a lot of "502 bad gateway" messages.

Replacing http.ListenAndServe() in main() with **appengine.Main()** fixed the context problem. Moving to **go111** instead of 112 took care of the other issue. The docs and examples are not very clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for migration to 1.12](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/go-differences) states:

> Use Cloud Tasks to enqueue tasks from Go 1.12 using the cloudtasks package. You can use any App Engine service as the target of an App Engine task.

But the cloudtasks package documentation (as at today’s date) is [clearly marked as beta and unstable](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/cloudtasks/apiv2beta3). So the answer here is probably. This feature is unsupported.

That said, I’m using it in production under go111 without any serious issue that I have noticed so far.

Comment: I think this worked for me, downgraded from go112 to go111 and there are no more `internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: service bridge HTTP failed: Post http://appengine.googleapis.internal:10001/rpc_http: dial tcp 169.254.169.253:10001: i/o timeout` problems. Previously I had 10s timeouts exactly, now my responses come at 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing `internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: service bridge HTTP failed` because you have `appengine.Main()` or other `appengine` lib calls while trying to run a Go 1.12+ runtime. (My guess is that the older runtime had to call into some Google-internal accounting infrastructure and that's not available for the 1.12 "next gen" systems.)

The solution isn't to downgrade your Go versions -- you're missing a ton of performance and security improvements doing that, and you can't take advantage of the new hardware -- the solution is to remove all the calls to the `appengine` lib and use GCP's cloud libraries instead (see https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go)